# clear the canvas draw programmatically Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-imageview

well i'v problem with `canvas.draw()` i'm having multiple frames to overlay on the same bitmap . and i succeed to do this. but the problem is when now it comes to apply another frame using the same methods but different border , the border overlay the old ones.

```
    void hm(){
    Bitmap border = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vignette2);
    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int height = bmp.getHeight();
    change = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(change, width, height, false);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(change);
    Bitmap scaledBorder = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(border,width,height, false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBorder, 0, 0,null);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(k, 0, 0, null);
    view.setImageBitmap(change);
    }
```

and here is the other method:

```
    void hm1(){
    Bitmap border = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.white);
    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int height = bmp.getHeight();
    change = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(change, width, height, false);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(change);
    Bitmap scaledBorder = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(border,width,height, false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBorder, 0, 0,null);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(k, 0, 0, null);
    view.setImageBitmap(change);
    }
```

now when i click on `button1` the overlay applies to the view. and when i click on `button2` it also applies to the view but it doesn't destroy the old border("the Overlay image"). 
i know that i should use different bitmap to handle every view of the imageview. but i'm using save button which will save the `Bitmap change` which means i want to apply the borders on this image and display it. without overlaying the old borders.
for example i'm using `QuickAction`and here is how i'm trying to accomplish the clicks.

```
                if (actionId == border0){
                hm();
                } 

             if (actionId == border1 ){
                 hm1();
                } 

              if (actionId == border2 ){
              }
```

it works but as i said it overlay the old ones .
any help will be thankful. 
thanks in advance.
Solved it tomorrow i will post the Answer :).

Answer (score 2):

Well you create a new bitmap based on the old one with this line:

```
change = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(change, width, height, false);
```

So make sure that you somehow reset the `change` bitmap with the original:

```
change = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, width, height, false);
```

Comment: and how to that ? i'm having an issue with this problem and i couldn't figure it out.!!! if i create a new bitmap based on the old one. is it going to be saved as change or not ?

Comment: Where ever you get create `change` for the first time. Keep it and use it there. Updating the answer

Comment: change is actually a bitmap from the original one !!!! .. which means before i wanna add the frame there is something i did with the (Bitmap change). i know i have to create a new bitmap to createScaledBitmap from the change, but i'm looking for another way without the need of using another bitmap. because if i did then i'v to create save method for it and if i did then its not looking professional because i already asking the user when he click save. i don't want to add a third question which will make it suck !

Comment: You should then consider a different approach. Anyway: You can't draw on the original one multiple times without expecting that the previous drawing will still be visible. Sounds more like a messy work flow in your app. Consider asking at a different time about saving...

Comment: yeah its kinda messy if do that. about saving method already succeed to accomplish it , before i even start coding my app. this is the not the problem. 
well i'm forced to use another bitmap and already did that. i'm playing with the save method now if i put 
change = newBitmap ; it will save the bitmap with the border, but when there is no border it will save it BLANK. 
tried it if(change == newBitmap) save change as newBitmap, else save change as its change. but no succeed !!!

Comment: well i figured it out, i was saving the Bitmap as bitmap , not the view as bitmap. :D later will post my answer
thanks for your help:)